# How to clear input fields after submit in react

Tags: reactjs, forms, email, material-ui, input-field

so i'm creating my portfolio and i am now on the final page, the contact page. I have it almost finished. I have it hooked up with emailjs and i receive emails with the message inputted as expected.

The problem i'm having is, when the form is submitted, i don't know how to clear the UI input fields. I could disregard using e.preventDefault(), however, i would like to keep that, as i want to style the page if the desired result has been achieved(message sent), or if an error has occurred. I would like to mention that i had used state for the name, email and message beforehand, however, i was unable to use the state variables in conjunction with the emailjs syntax, more specifically, with the "e.target" section. When the form is submitted, the result is the message being sent to my email, with the text inputted by the user still in the input fields.

The code is below, with some names left as hidden for privacy reasons:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Box, Grid, Typography, Button} from '@material-ui/core'
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Styles, { InputField } from './Styles'
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send'
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com'

function Contact() {
    const classes = Styles()

    function sendEmail(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'hidden', e.target, 'hidden')
          .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.text);
          result.text ==="OK" ? console.log("it worked") : console.log("didnt work")
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
      });
    }

    return (
        <Box component='div'>
            <Navbar/>
            <Grid container justify='center'>
                <Box component='form' className={classes.contactContainer} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                    <Typography variant='h5' className={classes.contactHead}>Contact Me</Typography>
                    <InputField
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    fullWidth={true}
                    label="Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin='dense'
                    size='medium'
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <InputField
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    fullWidth={true}
                    label="Email"
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin='dense'
                    size='medium'
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <InputField
                    id="message"
                    name="message"
                    fullWidth={true}
                    label="Enter Message Here"
                    multiline
                    rows={8}
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin='dense'
                    size='medium'
                    />
                    <br/>
                    <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant='outlined' 
                    fullWidth={true} 
                    endIcon={<SendIcon/>}
                    className={classes.contactButton}>
                        Contact Me
                    </Button>
                </Box>
            </Grid>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default Contact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simplest way to do it in your code, use useState to declare initial value of the fields such as:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
```

Then you need to set the "value" param in your InputField component, eg:

```
<InputField
   id="name"
   name="name"
   fullWidth={true}
   label="Name"
   variant="outlined"
   margin='dense'
   size='medium'
   value={name}
 />
```

And after receiving the result in emailjs.sendForm, use setName to reset the value of the name field, eg:

```
setName("")
```

Use the similar method for other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the answer, it helped, however did not fully fix the problem. That being said, i was able to find a solution. I used the onChange param and passed through a function which changes the state AND the value. Also, after receiving the result in emailjs.sendForm, i reset the value of all the fields.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.target.name=="name" 
    ? setName(event.target.value)
    : event.target.name=="email" 
    ? setEmail(event.target.value)
    : event.target.name=="message" 
    ? setMessage(event.target.value)
    : console.log("error")
  };

function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'hiddenForPrivacy', e.target, 'hiddenForPrivacy')
  .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
      result.text ==="OK" ? console.log("it worked") : alert("didnt work")
      setName("")
      setMessage("")
      setEmail("")
  }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
  });
}
```

The input fields now look like this:

```
return (
    <Box component='div'>
        <Navbar/>
        <Grid container justify='center'>
            <Box component='form' className={classes.contactContainer} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                <Typography variant='h5' className={classes.contactHead}>Contact Me</Typography>
                <InputField
                id="name"
                name="name"
                fullWidth={true}
                label="Name"
                variant="outlined"
                margin='dense'
                size='medium'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                value={name}
                />
                <br/>
                <InputField
                id="email"
                name="email"
                fullWidth={true}
                label="Email"
                variant="outlined"
                margin='dense'
                size='medium'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                value={email}
                />
                <br/>
                <InputField
                id="message"
                name="message"
                fullWidth={true}
                label="Enter Message Here"
                multiline
                rows={8}
                variant="outlined"
                margin='dense'
                size='medium'
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                value={message}
                />
                <br/>
                <Button
                type="submit"
                variant='outlined' 
                fullWidth={true} 
                endIcon={<SendIcon/>}
                className={classes.contactButton}>
                    Contact Me
                </Button>
            </Box>
        </Grid>
    </Box>
```